# ASP.NET MVC5 what files to upload to goDaddy and to what directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, asp.net-mvc-5

I've checked out the other questions, but none seem to answer the question I'm looking for. I have an ASP.NET MVC5 web application that I want to deploy to my Windows goDaddy account. goDaddy assures me that I have the correct type of windows hosting. Another thread mentioned that I should build my project on my local machine, make sure it works, and then FTP my build files to goDaddy. I would like to clarify what I upload to goDaddy. When I ran the build in MS Visual Studio 2012 Express, it listed this "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MySite\bin\MySite.dll".

So, when I FTP something up to goDaddy, do I just upload MySite.dll, or do I start at MySite and upload all of that?

Second, I've seen a few posts say to create a directory under the default httpdocs on goDaddy - is this just best practice or do I need to? - can anyone confirm that? With that said, if I need to create another directory, I assume I upload my files there. If I don't need to create a new directory, do I just upload my files under the root httpdocs?

Comment: First of all, have you built and published the website? On Visual Studio select the web project, right click and select publish from the menu to publish the website.

Comment: Yep, I did a file publish to a pubs folder I created. So, I assume I upload all the files in the pubs directory to a directory on goDaddy. Do I upload to a special directory I created or just to the default root directory httpdocs? A confusing thing is that my httpdocs directory already has an index.html - not sure how/if I override that with the publish files. Thanks

Comment: Yes. You have to upload or FTP all the files in the published folder into the  httpdocs folder in Plex. Before you upload anything just check if the index.html file is under httpdocs and you can browse the site. Check: https://au.godaddy.com/help/getting-started-with-hosting-plesk-8845

Comment: Thanks again, I got the files uploaded. Now just need to deal with an application error message relating to Web.Configuration file. Maybe another post.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, I had similar problems with web.config, it seems that godaddy doesn´t let me to configure the 4.5 framework for httpdocs folder, I resolved it creating new virtual directory and setting up the correct .net framework, don´t forget to configure that new folder as your default for your domain, and yes you need to copy your application to the new folder.